# ajax response not comes in ajax form submition with jquery validation

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter, jquery-validate, smarty

My code is this in which form submition is working throgh ajax with jquery form validation but response not working..

my ajax code :

```
$("#save_form4").validate({ 
        rules: {
            name: {
                required: true          
            },
            min_salary:{
                required: true,
                number: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            name: {
                required:  "Job Title is required."                 
            },
            min_salary:{
                required: "Min Salary is required.",
                number: "Enter Valid Amount."
            }
        },
        // the errorPlacement has to take the table layout into account
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            if ( element.is(":radio") )
                error.insertAfter( element.parent() );
            else if ( element.is(":checkbox") )
                error.insertAfter( element.next() );
            else{
                if(element.is("textarea"))
                error.insertAfter(element.next());
            else
                error.insertAfter( element );
            }               
        },
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            var formVars = $(form).serialize();
            $(form).ajaxSubmit({
                type:     'POST',
                url:     '{/literal}{$site_url}vacancies/vacancy_job/{$id}{literal}',
                async : false,
                data:     formVars,
                cache: false,
                success: function(data)
                { alert('hjkhjh');
                      $('#job_panel').css('display','none');
                      $('#job').html(data);
                },
                error : function(){
                    alert('error');
                }
            });
            return false;
        }

    });
```

here in ajax response any alert is not working but it goes in vacancies controller and save data also....anybody please help me.

Comment: Try } this symbol move to line with word "success"

Comment: @dikkini that wont make any difference..!

Comment: did you check browser console... what does it say..?

Comment: yes it gives me response completely in browser console but its not gone in success...

Comment: However it gives you completely response in console if you did not show it there (console.log)?

Comment: it gives me that response in console which functionality I have done in vacancy_job function and make return data from its, its gives me response but not in success (data) from where I have to replace that data with div id job.

Comment: Please post the code of the method you are calling. It could be that you are not sending anything from the server side.

Comment: I have checked it that it gives response from server side. only not comes in success....

Comment: Also show the relevant HTML markup for the form.  See:  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Is your page reloading when you submit?  You're using the `.ajaxSubmit()` method from the Forms plugin.  Have you properly included the Malsup Forms plugin?

Comment: I'm voting to close because not enough code is shown to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure but it seems that you dont' send data via AJAX but with standard POST and that's why data is stored on server side.

I copied your code to my form and data was being sent via POST not via AJAX. The problem is that you use `ajaxSubmit` what is the part of `jQuery Form Plugin` and probably you haven't added this file to your JS files and in html document.

But this plugin is not necessary in this case I think.

When you change:

```
$(form).ajaxSubmit({
```

into

```
$.ajax({
```

and of course you reload page, you should see your Javascript alerts as you wanted. I've changed it in your code on my test site and Javascript alerts were displayed.

Comment: It's possible that the OP has not implemented `.validate()` properly and the default action on the form is taking over.  In that case, the page would be re-loading.  However, then it wouldn't matter if he's using `.ajax()` or `.ajaxSubmit()`.  Otherwise, if `.validate()` is working properly, we do not know if he's properly included the Malsup Forms plugin.  With such a poorly written question, I think your answer should have been a series of questions on the OP instead.

Comment: Thank you so much Marcin Nabialek, Its working fine now and also thanks to everybody who helps me.